# How to use PDPageContentStream addRect() method to draw a rectangle on text extraction accurately?

Tags: java, pdfbox, text-extraction

In the code below here, I was using Point2D and Dimension 2D to get the coordinate of the text.

```
try {
    PdfTextFindCollection pdfTextFindCollection = page.findText(result.trim());
    PdfTextFind[] extractedResult = pdfTextFindCollection.getFinds();

    for (PdfTextFind find : extractedResult) {
        Point2D pointF = find.getPosition();
        Dimension2D widthHeight = find.getSize();
        double x = pointF.getX();
        double y = pointF.getY();
        double width = widthHeight.getWidth();
        double height = widthHeight.getHeight();
        position.setX(x);
        position.setY(y);
        position.setHeight(height);
        position.setWidth(width);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    
}
```

After I get the coordinate of the text, I need to draw a rectangle on it.

```
try ( PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page, PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.APPEND, true, true)) {
    contentStream.saveGraphicsState();
    contentStream.transform(Matrix.getScaleInstance(1, -1));
    contentStream.transform(Matrix.getTranslateInstance(0, -page.getCropBox().getHeight()));
    contentStream.saveGraphicsState();
    contentStream.setStrokingColor(Color.RED);
    contentStream.addRect(positionPropertyUnitX, positionPropertyUnitY, positionPropertyUnitWidth, positionPropertyUnitHeight);
}
```

**Output:-**
[image]

**Questions:-**
How to make the coordinate of "PDPageContentStream addRect" same as the coordinate of "PdfTextFind[]" text position? So that the rectangle can be drawn accurately from start to end of the text extraction.

Comment: For the width, try `PDFont.getStringWidth(text)`. Getting the exact height is more difficult, you'd need to render the glyphs, see the `DrawPrintTextLocations.java` example how this is done.

Comment: What exactly is `PdfTextFind`? How are the result coordinates specified to be?

Comment: Hi @mkl, PdfTextFind actually is one of the libraries under com.spire.pdf. The purpose is to find the text from the pdf page. If the text is found inside the pdf, I would need to get the text coordinate and draw a rectangle on it.

Comment: And *how are the* `PdfTextFind` *result coordinates specified to be?*

Comment: I'm using Point2D to get the x and y values while Dimension 2D is for me to get the width and height values.

Comment: Lets assume that the PdfTextFind coordinates are "somehow" correct, then your question is really just about how to map these to your PDF changes, so no need to calculate font sizes, the problem is rather what these coordinates mean. What you could do is to run PDFDebugger with your PDF and hover your mouse to a place where you found something, in the hope that this shows what relationship there is. (Note that PDF coordinates start at the bottom left)

Comment: Just like @Tilman said, to help you transforming coordinates returned by some other software to the coordinate system used by PDFBox (which in this case is the native PDF user space coordinate system), we need to know how the coordinate system used by that other software is defined. I hoped you could look that up in the documentation of that other software while Tilman's approach is more of a trial&error way (the remaining option if the documentation of that other software is not helpful).